# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "sin embargo"?

Tags: etimología

La frase "sin embargo" se traduce como "however" en inglés, pero no la entiendo.

La palabra "sin" significa "without", y la palabra "embargo" significa "ban" o lo mismo que la palabra inglesa "embargo".

Así que a mí me parece que la traducción literal de "sin embargo" en inglés es "without embargo", que no tiene sentido.

¿Cuál es la etimología de la frase "sin embargo"?

Comment: "Without embargo" would have nearly the same meaning in English, "without holding back" or as said below, "without impediment." "However" means the same thing, "how ever" or "without anything getting in the way."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## English

"Sin embargo" is an adversative idiom meaning nevertheless or without setting any impediment.

From [DRAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=%20embargo):

> sin embargo.
>
> 1. *locución conjuntiva adversativa*. No obstante, sin que sirva de impedimento.

As it is an idiom, it doesn't make much sense to make comparisons with it's English counterpart. But let's see how it comes to mean this in Spanish, why it means "without setting an impediment".

"Sin" means "lack of" (without). "Embargo" can mean [more than one thing](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=%20embargo), and we find this:

> 5. *anticuado*. Daño, incomodidad.

We see that "embargo" was used in the past as "harm, inconvenience". So "sin embargo" means "without inconvenience", which is pretty similar to "without any impediment".

> Frase A. Sin embargo, frase B adversa a A.
>
> Statement A. However, statement B contrasting A.

This means that the previous statement to "sin embargo" is not an obstacle to state the following one, being the latter a contrast. This is actually the same as "nevertheless" and "however".

---

## Español

"Sin embargo" es una locución verbal adversativa [que significa](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=%20embargo):

> 1. *locución conjuntiva adversativa*. No obstante, sin que sirva de impedimento.

Como es una locución, no tiene mucho sentido hacer comparaciones con su correspondiente en inglés. Pero veamos de donde viene este significado en español, por qué significa "sin que sirva de impedimento".

"Embargo" puede significar [más de una cosa](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=%20embargo), y nos encontramos con esto:

> 5. *anticuado*. Daño, incomodidad.

Vemos que "embargo" se usaba como "daño o incomodidad". Por tanto, "sin embargo" significa "sin incomodidad", que es parecido a "sin impedimento".

> Frase A. Sin embargo, frase B adversa a A.

Esto significa que la frase previa a "sin embargo" no es un obstáculo para decir la frase que la sigue siendo esta última contraria a la primera.

Comment: Speaking of *obstacles*, there's "no *obstante*", which means roughly the same as "sin embargo".

Answer (score 7):

La palabra latina ***imbarricare*** significa **"poner barreras"**, o sea, obstaculizar, impedir. Está formada por la preposición *in* ("en"), más el sustantivo *barra* ("barrera").

Curiosamente evolucionó hacia la palabra jurídica *embargar*, que originalmente significaba "dificultar", y se refería a tomar precauciones para que un acusado no se escapara con lo robado, poniéndole guardias o dejando en custodia sus bienes.

Pero siguiendo su propia historia, *embargo* como "con-barrera" pasó al olvido y quedó sólo en la expresión ***sin embargo***, que significa entonces literalmente "sin con-barrera".

Era una forma culta de indicar que hay un obstáculo que puede ser sorteado, del mismo modo que ***pese a*** o ***a pesar de***. Todavía se usa bastante con ese significado:

> Llueve. **Sin embargo** seguiremos adelante. [la lluvia es el obstáculo sorteado]

Con el paso del tiempo perdió ese requerimiento y hoy se usa como sinónimo de ***pero***, es decir, ya no necesita que el antecesor sea un obstáculo negativo. Lo que indica es que la frase anterior y la posterior son semánticamente positiva y negativa, o viceversa.

> Era la más bonita y sin embargo no ganó el concurso.

Aquí "ser bonita" no es ningún obstáculo, a menos que se fuerce bastante la lógica. Simplemente ser bonita es "bueno" y perder es "malo".

En otra historia, *imbarricare* pasó al francés en la palabra *barricade* ("barricada", "parapeto"), que no tiene nada que ver con las *barricas* ("odres").

Comment: +1, qué bien documentado.

Answer (score 0):

Para conocer la expresión "sin embargo", primero hay que reconocer la expresión "empero", que posee el mismo significado de "sin embargo". Este "empero" proviene de la unión de "en" y "pero", del latín per hoc = "por esto, por lo tanto".

Así la expresión "Sin embargo", con el sentido de; "a pesar de lo dicho", "a pesar de esto", "sin perjuicio de lo dicho"... proviene de la antigua palabra "sine" + el verbo, "sine + valgo" sin valor de esto", que alargara el sonido "e" para añadir n/m - Sinem. Verbo Valeo> Valo> Valgo (valer). Por rotación "valgo" se muto a "vargo/bargo", con el sentido, sin valor de lo dicho, sin valor de esto, de lo establecido, sin tener en cuenta, "*sin valor de esto*, lo dicho anteriormente, no impide que...", dando lugar a nuestro "Sin embargo" actual.
No tiene nada que ver con "imbarricare", barreras, ni nada por el estilo.

Diego