# How does "sin impedimento" translate to "however, nonetheless, still"?

Tags: traducción, inglés

[embargo | Definición | Diccionario de la lengua española | RAE - ASALE](https://dle.rae.es/embargo#1Zo0amT)

> #### sin embargo
>
> 1. loc. adv. Sin que sirva de impedimento. *Resulta verosímil y, sin embargo, hay que ponerlo en duda. Jugó bien, pero no logró ganar, sin embargo.*

[English Translation of “sin embargo” | Collins Spanish-English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/sin-embargo)

> ### sin embargo
>
> however ⧫ nonetheless ⧫ still

I know that "Sin que sirva de impedimento." means "without serving as an impediment", or more briefly, "Sin <s>que sirva de</s> impedimento."= "without <s>serving as an</s> impediment". But how does "sin impedimento"  signify "however, nonetheless, still"?

This doesn't duplicate [¿Cuál es la etimología de "sin embargo"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2305), because it doesn't engage the English translations. Here's [Etymonline on "embargo"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/embargo#etymonline_v_5770) for context.

> ## embargo (n.)
>
> "order forbidding ships from certain other nations from entering or leaving a nation's ports," 1590s, from Spanish *embargo* "seizure, arrest; embargo," noun of action from *embargar* "restrain, impede, arrest, embargo," from Vulgar Latin **imbarricare*, from assimilated form of in- "into, upon" (from PIE root [*en](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*en?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "in") + *barra (see [bar](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bar?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_5227) (n.1)).

Comment: The answer provided in the linked question does engage the English translation specifically.

Comment: *Impedir* means *prevent*. The translation of "sin que sirva de impedimento" is roughly "the previous statement does not prevent the next statement".

Comment: @RubioRic Where?

Comment: "As it is an idiom, it doesn't make much sense to make comparisons with it's English counterpart. But let's see how it comes to mean this in Spanish, why it means "without setting an impediment ...". The answer addressed the comparison between Spanish and English in the use of this element.